# Modifyrepo functionality in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

am changing my base os from centos to ubuntu
i had custom repos in centos which i have now created using dpkg-scanpackages,
so now i need the funtionality of modifyrepo which works on rpm metadata file.
but now it should consider the debian packages metadata and modify the Packages.gz file
so how can i achive it in ubuntu

Comment: Given that very few people who know debian-style repos well are also equally familiar with rpm specific tools, you probably should mention what `modifyrepo` does AND what, specifically, *you* use it for.  i.e. what package metadata do you want to change?  That way, you might get someone with debian expertise to tell you if what you want to do is possible (or even needed) and if so, how.

Comment: modifyrepo /tmp/build/updateinfo-`echo el7 | grep -o -P '.{0,1}$'`/updateinfo.xml /tmp/install/scratch/iso-root/repodata/
in the above they have used satatement to update some info like this and after updating the metadata then again placing the the same info in different directory

well modifyrepo command is used to add/insert arbitrary metadata from xml file to the repomd file inside repodata